# The sphere with three ends?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

[image]

The preceding image take form *Matthias Weber's* *[Classical Minimal Surfaces in Euclidean Space by Examples](http://www.indiana.edu/~minimal/research/claynotes.pdf)* notes is called the sphere with three ends. But what does it have to do with a sphere and why do we say it has three ends? What is formally the end of a surface?

Comment: I can't answer your important questions, but [here](https://i.imgur.com/Gok6Ng1.jpg) I've highlighted the three ends. Topologically, it's just a disc with two holes in it, but I'm sure there is something about the curvature which makes the geometry on that surface special and / or cool.

Answer (score 0):

Math people, like many other people, tend to use heavy slang, about as cryptic as [criminal argot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot) at its worst. Luckily for us, they usually leave behind a trail of definitions which theoretically can be followed.

This surface has nothing to do with a sphere, except that it is a [minimal surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface) (which a sphere is not), and hence can be made of soap film, much like a soap bubble, which **is** a sphere. Unlike a bubble, though, it has got to have *borders*. Imagine a weirdly bent soap film stretched on a few pieces of wire. (These, BTW, are the *ends* of the surface; for more formal definition look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology))).

So it goes.